# How to install and launch PostgreSQL as part of a stand-alone Python-based application?

Tags: postgresql, installation, pyinstaller

I have created a Python application that utilizes a PostgreSQL database and now I'd like to package it as a stand-alone application. I have worked out how to package everything as a single executable using [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) however it will fail upon launch when attempting to establish a connection to the database if it doesn't exist. To address this my assumption is that I need to also include a mechanism for installing and launching a PostgreSQL database instance if it's not present.

I'm trying to provide a single installation process that creates/configures/launches the database (if not present) and installs the application's executable. I want to create installers for Linux, Windows, and MacOS.

How do I best go about this? I am hoping to find documentation for a solution to this use case -- my Google-Fu appears to be weak and/or the solution is obscure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling external software is not the purpose of Pyinstaller. So you need to handle its dependencies by yourself. So about your question, you need to first find a portable version of PostgreSQL, then in your script, run and configure it manually. For example, there is a good portable version in [here](https://github.com/garethflowers/postgresql-portable).
Just extract the contents of PGRE portable to a directory like `PostgreSQL` next to your python script (`app.py`).
Then you can use the below code to launch Database:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

PGRE_EXE = "PostgreSQL/PostgreSQLPortable.exe"


def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


def start_pgre():
    pgre_path = os.path.join(resource_path("."), PGRE_EXE)
    print(pgre_path)
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        [pgre_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_pgre()
```

Then add the whole `PostgreSQL` as external data with [`--add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files):

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "./PostgreSQL:PostgreSQL" app.py
```

Comment: How to close when user is closing our exe ?